# Resolve the error "PHPMailer Error: Extension missing: openssl"

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've removed ; for openssl from php.ini at php as well as apache folder. I still get the error "PHPMailer Error: Extension missing: openssl" The following is the php code and I've setup phpmailerautoload too.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
require "PHPMailerAutoload.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
// or try these settings (worked on XAMPP and WAMP):
/*$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';*/


$mail->Username = "vignesh*******45@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "********";

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.

$mail->From = "vignesh*******45@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Vignesh";

$mail->addAddress("vignesh*******45@gmail.com","User 1");

//$mail->addCC("user.3@ymail.com","User 3");
//$mail->addBCC("user.4@in.com","User 4");

$mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
$mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Please help me in resolving the error. I've enabled openssl in wampserver too.

Comment: The error message says that you are missing the openssl extension... did you double check? aka, did you edit the correct ini files?

Comment: Also check here, there could be some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host?rq=1

Comment: edit php.ini file, remove the";" at the ";extension=php_openssl.dll"

Answer (score 7):

PHP on IIS,

1) Open
(php install directory)php.ini

2) Uncomment (~ line 910 in php.ini)
extension=php_openssl.dll

3) Restart IIS

Comment: Nope didnt work. None of these suggestions worked. Im using Windows 10 and PHP 7.4.10

Answer (score 2):

For Windows + Apache:

In PHP.INI, un-comment `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

In Apache\bin, add `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. (Skipping this step causes Apache startup to twice say `The ordinal 3906 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll.`)

Restart Apache.

The next step is getting the SSL stuff working - TLS versus SSL, port number, authentication ...

Answer (score 1):

change `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini` file.
then restart your webbrowser and wamp/xampp server. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you did and what @Bilbo said, you might want to change the value form `extension_dir` in your php.ini to an absolute path (instead of the relative default). Not sure why, but that did the trick for me.

In your php.ini find and change `extension_dir = "ext"` to something like this: `extension_dir = "c:/php710/ext"`. **Your path may vary!**

Answer (score 0):

1) Open (php install directory) php.ini
Tip: If you can't find your php.ini you can create a php file and run it as follows:

```
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();
 if ($inipath) {
      echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
 } else {
      echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
 }
```

This will tell you where your php.ini or if you dont have one loaded.
Tip: php comes with a production and development php.ini if you need one.

2) Uncomment (~ line 910 in php.ini)
Pre 7.4.2: `extension=php_openssl.dll`
7.4.2: `extension=openssl`

3) Uncomment `extension_dir = "ext"` (~line 761 in php.ini)

4) Restart IIS

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was the space in the path of "ext" dir: `c:/Program files/php-5.4.36/exe`.

Once changed, the ext dir to a "solid" path *(simply copying into a place having a path without spaces inside)* and phpmail `(PHPMailer->SMTPSecure("tls"))` works perfectly fine!

Obviously in the php.ini file, the row `extension=php_openssl.dll` is to be uncommented!

Curiously, after this work through, the execution of the command line scripts only resumed after restarting the command shell (cmd).