# PHPMailer fails to connect to google smtp server under debian

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, debian, phpmailer

I am trying to send an e-mail with PHPMailer. Here is my function to send an e-mail. It is working fine on localhost from an Ubuntu 14.04.

```
function smtpMail($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
   $mail = new PHPMailer;
   $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // tells PHPMailer to use SMTP
   $mail->Host       = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');  // sets the hostname of the mail server
   $mail->Port       = 587;                              // sets the SMTP port number
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // sets the encryption system to use
   $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                                   // debug level
   $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                             // whether to use SMTP authentication
   $mail->Username   = 'jdoe@company.org';            // username to use for SMTP authentication
   $mail->Password   = 'qwerty';                     // password to use for SMTP authentication
   $mail->CharSet    = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);                    // sets who the message is to be sent from
   $mail->Subject = $subject;
   $mail->Body = $body;
   $mail->AddAddress($to);
   if (!$mail->Send ()) {
           return 'Mail error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           //return 'KO';
   }
   return 'OK';
}
```

Now I am trying to deploy it on a server. The code is the same but it is not working anymore. The server is an apache2 running inside a debian 8.2.
PHPMailer prints these lines.

```
2015-12-09 13:35:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2015-12-09 13:35:41 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2015-12-09 13:35:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-12-09 13:35:41 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2015-12-09 13:35:41 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
```

From the server the following commands are working fine :

```
dig smtp.gmail.com
ping smtp.gmail.com
telnet smtp.gmail.com
```

I tried to send an e-mail with telnet and it is also working. I followed this [tutorial](http://furie.be/news/38/15/Tester-le-SMTP-de-Gmail-via-Telnet.html) (sorry it's in french)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Try `SMTPDebug = 4` and see if it tells you anything new. Looks like you may be missing an SSL extension or have an outdated CA file, or your ISP is redirecting you, causing a verification failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371910/phpmailer-generates-php-warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate)

It appears that my certificates were not matching.