# Gmail smtp is not working in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

This my code,

```
require_once("PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
/* receiver details and message - start */
$toid = "example@gmail.com";
$toname = "Example";

$msg = "First name : ".$_POST["fname"] . "<br>";
$msg .= "Last name : ".$_POST["lname"]. "<br>";;
$msg .= "Email : ".$_POST["email"]. "<br>";;
$msg .= "Mobile : ".$_POST["mobile"]. "<br>";;
$msg .= "Message : ".$_POST["msg"];
$subject = "sample subject";
/* receiver details and message - end */

$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  

/* mail smtp configuration - start */
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';  
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
/* mail smtp configuration - end */

$mail->From = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "from name";


$mail->AddAddress($toid, $toname);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $msg;
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
if($mail->Send()){
echo "success";
}else{
echo "Failure";
}
```

When run the above , it throws

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php on line 200

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371910/phpmailer-generates-php-warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate

Comment: I'm not PHP guy but in C# I had similar problem when trying to send email by gmail. Solved after setting SSL=true in my request.

Comment: There have been a flurry of issues like this in the last week - I suspect gmail has changed a root certificate that's missing from many PHP installations, so try updating your CA certificates as the troubleshooting guide and PHP docs say. It's not this problem, but you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, so get the latest.

Comment: i checked with latest also throws same error @Synchro

Comment: That's why I said "It's not this problem". Fix your certs, do what the guide says.

Answer (score 0):

It's got nothing to do with your code - your OpenSSL CA cert store does not contain the CA cert and/or your system is running in an environment which masquerades the gmail service and/or your clock is *very* wrong and/or you are using a *very* old version of openSSL. You've told us nothing about the platform this sits on so we can't advise how to fix this.

BTW you'll also need to enable "insecure" connectivity at the google side - I don't think PHPmailer supports oauth over SMTP.

Comment: PHPMailer has supported SMTP XOAUTH2 for a few years. See [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps), but that doesn't have anything to do with validating Gmail's certificate, which happens long before any authentication.

Comment: I aready enabled the "insecure" connectivity at the google side... bt didn't wrk yet.

Comment: @Renu: your client has to connect before it can authenticate.

Comment: @symcbean : I didn't get it..?

Answer (score -1):

For GMail, change your setup to:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Comment: It throws same error, SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failure

Comment: Nope. Also, don't post unexplained code as an answer, say *why* you think it fixes the problem, though in this case it doesn't.