# PHP sending email with SMTP error : Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto():Language string failed to load: tls

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I would send email with SMTP in PHP. I use Gmail SMTP.

My code :

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'egenthiers.80@gmail.com';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'XXXX';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'egenthiers.80@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Egen Can';
$mail->AddAddress('egenthiers.63@gmail.com', 'Egen Can');  // Add a recipient

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

When I run this code. I get this error :

> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code
>   1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\PHPMailer_5.2.0\class.smtp.php on line
>   200 Language string failed to load: tls Message could not be
>   sent.Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: tls SMTP server
>   error:

How can I solve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: upload it to server and try this. **By default, localhost won't send emails unless you configure it** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8/30610643#30610643

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I did it. But didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer generates PHP Warning: stream\_socket\_enable\_crypto(): Peer certificate did not match expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371910/phpmailer-generates-php-warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Mistake 1:

```
require 'PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php';
```

You're using a very, very old version of PHPMailer that is buggy and subject to numerous security holes. [Upgrade immediately](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Mistake 2:

```
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:
certificate verify failed
```

Not [searching for this error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+certificate+verify+failed) means that you have not found the many, many answers and [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure) that addresses this exact problem.

The documentation covers this extensively. It's most likely that your server's CA certificate bundle is outdated (especially given you're using such an old version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on a very old example).

Comment: You are just. I changed this  '$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";' to ssl. I solved this error. But I got other error :) This error : 'Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\PHPMailer_5.2.0\class.smtp.php on line 215
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate' 
If I download the new PHPMailer, will the problem be solved?

Comment: `ssl` mode on port 587 will not work, as you would know if you had read the documentation I pointed you at. I'm not going to troubleshoot problems on old versions.