# Message: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`some-address-here` did not match expected CN=`127.0.0.1'

Tags: smtp, gmail, certificate, peer

I want to send an email using gmail but it has error as shown:

Message: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`some-address-here` did not match expected CN=`127.0.0.1'

Filename: PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php

Message was not sentMailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Kindly help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In drupal following one of its solutions worked for me, you may find your solution in the given link. [PHPMailer generates PHP Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate did not match expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371910/phpmailer-generates-php-warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate)

For me, this solution worked, Disable SMTP restrictions in WHM by searching SMTP.
I was facing the same issue. Follow the reference, it might help you to find settings.

stream_socket_enable_crypto():

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you used ssl connection on 465 port instead tls on 587.