# stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.hostingcare.net' did not match expected CN=`mail.domain.com'

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am trying to send mail in codeigniter but this error message comes

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.hostingcare.net' did not match expected CN=`mail.domain.com'.

I googled this error for long hours but cat find solution.

This is my config setting

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.domain.com', // changed this
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'info@domain.com',// changed this
        'smtp_pass' => '*******',// changed this
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'smtp_crypto'  => 'tls',
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer generates PHP Warning: stream\_socket\_enable\_crypto(): Peer certificate did not match expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371910/phpmailer-generates-php-warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate)

Comment: but i am not using PHPMailer im using codeigniter default email code.

Comment: As far as I can see it doesn't matter what framework/library you're using. It's not a problem with the framework/library itself, it's a problem with the certificate. And because of that I would say it's a duplicate.

Comment: so where can i check whether my certificate is dublicate or not

Comment: ?! Your certificate is not a duplicate. Your question is.

Comment: You are saying its a duplicate. i dont understand what is a duplicate.. can u clarify more ?

Comment: Another user already posted a question where he basically asked the same thing you just asked. In my first comment is a link to a question where he had the exact same error message and there you can see it's an openssl error caused by a ssl misconfiguration of some sort, not an error from codeigniter directly.

Comment: If you edit your title @Muhammad Ramzan to indicate that this error message is encountered in CodeIgniter, the question can be useful to help others find the same solution in similar circumstances.  For example " Sending mail in CodeIgniter site generates PHP Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate did not match expected."

Comment: Same issue is discussed here but using Laravel framework
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688060/laravel-9-error-laravel-email-unable-to-connect-with-starttls-stream-socket-e