# LARAVEL 9. ERROR LARAVEL EMAIL: Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

Greetings to the community!

I have recently developed a web page with **Laravel 9.X**, which works correctly in local, but when I upload it to my Host, I am having problems with sending emails.

When I have been testing locally, it has been working correctly, and I have been using **mailtrap**. Now that I have uploaded it to the server, I have my own SMTP, and it is not working for me. I have the **ssl** certificate created, but there is no way it will send me any mail. I get the following error:

*Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed*.

SSL working fine when i visit the site with https.

I have configured my `.env` file, where I have put:

`HOST`: my smtp server; `PORT`: 587; `ENCRYPTION TYPE`: SSL; `USERNAME AND PASSWORD`: Those of my email account.

I have been touching also my file located in `config/mail.php`, putting the same configuration as in the `.env` file. I have also tried with other ports like 25, 465... among others.

I have tried to access the mail account from **outlook**, using the `IMAP` protocol, and I have been able to connect correctly, so the mail can be accessed.

I have checked lot of things in Google, and also every blogs y found in Stack Overflow, but nothing worked.

Any idea what is going on?
Am I missing something to configure?

Comment: The error says that the security certificate encountered when connecting to your email is invalid.  Can you add more information about it?  common name?  SAN?  certificate authority?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I had this problem after upgrading to the new 9 version, so you need to follow two steps.

1. Edit your `.env` file located in the root of the project The place where your mail settings are described, change `tls` to `null`. If you do not have such a line, then add

   **MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null**
2. If you have version 8 then this will be enough, but in version Laravel 9 you will need to open the file `app/config/mail.php` Find a section `mailers smtp` add two options  `'auth_mode' => null` and `'verify_peer' => false` an example of how it would look

   ```
   'mailers' => [
            'smtp' => [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
                'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
                'timeout' => null,


                'auth_mode'  => null,
                'verify_peer'       => false,
            ],
   ```

Comment: You are right, but in my case, i just needed to add `'verify_peer' => false`, didnt put `'auth_mode' => null`, and my encryptation type is ssl right now. It works correctly. Thank you

Comment: It works for me, actually because I upgrade my old version project to laravel 9, the Mail config is for the old version, and after updating it to the latest version, I set two parameters `verify_peer`  and  `verify_peer_name`  with `false` value and my problem was solved

Comment: As the documentation (https://laravel.su/docs/9.x/upgrade) says, the `auth_mode` is not required but the `verify_peer` is needed to disable TLS peer verification. In my case setting `verify_peer` to `false` fixed the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to run ```php artisan config:cache``` after you make changes.

Comment: @user2511140  after running this, the project is not reading data from env at all!