# Laravel 9 Unable to connect with STARTTLS Error code 1 but another laravel 9 app works?

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I have this leave capturing app that will need to send emails, it uses ldap to authenticate for the login and getting the users data.

After adding the email class, controller, view, routes etc i get the... Unable to connect with STARTTLS: code 1 Error and iv'e tried the following without any success...

[Tried this no success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688060/laravel-9-error-laravel-email-unable-to-connect-with-starttls-stream-socket-e)

[Even tried for older laravel no success](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-laravel-7)

[This as well no success](https://laravelamit.medium.com/stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-openssl-error-messages-75091edbd75d)

I've also tried other mail providers to no success.

The very strange thing is that i created a "empty" new Laravel 9 app with the same setup and i have no issues sending mails and the setup is literally the same, just without all the stuff built for the leave capturing.

My setup is as follows...

.env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Log::info('mail ');
        $testMailData = [
            'title' => 'Test Email From AllPHPTricks.com',
            'body' => 'This is the body of test email.'
        ];

        Mail::to('your_email@gmail.com')->send(new SendMail($testMailData));

        dd('Success! Email has been sent successfully.');
    }
}
```

route

```
Route::get('email', [EmailController::class, 'index']);
```

sendmail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $testMailData;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($testMailData)
    {
        $this->testMailData = $testMailData;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Email From AllPHPTricks.com')
                    ->view('emails.testMail');
    }
}
```

my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AllPHPTricks.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ $testMailData['title'] }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $testMailData['body'] }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out this line `'auth_mode' => null` in `config/mail.php`.