# Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465"

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, laravel-9

I'm trying to register into a project in laravel 9 that require verification email to login, but it keeps give me this error:

> Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

this is my .env:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxx@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

and this is the mail config file:

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

any ideas, How can I solve it?

I tried this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
```

but it doesn't work

Edit: I found the solution here and it works
[LARAVEL 9. ERROR LARAVEL EMAIL: Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688060/laravel-9-error-laravel-email-unable-to-connect-with-starttls-stream-socket-e)

Comment: Looks like an issue with outdated CA on your hosting platform. It does not look like a coding issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know a few solution:

> **Solution 1:** If u have another AV, like Avast, please disable it to run the test. Some AV have Core Shield about Mail Shield. This is
> prevent a malicious mail being delivered or retrieved.

Another solution:

> **Solution 2:** Go to `config/mail.php`
> Add this line below in inside `mailers => smtp` after `'timeout' => null,`

```
'stream' => [
     'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
   ],
],
```

Another solution (Not Recommended):

> **Solution 3:** Go to `vendor\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\Streambuffer.php` Comment this code: `$options = [];` and add after with this: `$options['ssl'] = array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true);`