# PHPMailer throws error when sending mail from a free subdomain

Tags: php, email, subdomain, phpmailer

I am using `PHPMailer` 5.2.0 for sending mail from localhost using my `GMAIL` account, it works perfectly, but when I hosted whole contents to a free sub-domain in `getmeleave.orgfree.com`, I get a error message as follows

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Please give me solution for this, as it is my final year project. 
Thank you

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: Search before posting (there are many duplicates of this question), and read the PHPMailer docs. If you're running 5.2.0, that is truly ancient - upgrade to [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

In many case with this issue, Solution like lack of *SSL* support in PHP. So you need to enable like:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

If not solve this?. I suggest you to enable the SMTP debug available on the SMTP configuration page and then try to send an email. It will give you a more detailed story of why you can't send the message.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

Once you set true it will report you what is the *SMTP* error.