# sending mail through PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, error-handling, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail through PHP Mailer and i have got a error like this

**Error:**

> SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError s8sm44466998pfj.45 - gsmtp
>   The following From address failed:my email address@gmail.com : MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError s8sm44466998pfj.45 - gsmtp,530,5.5.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required. Learn more at 
>   Message cannot be send

```
   <?php

require_once ('PHPMailer-master/class.pop3.php');
require_once ('PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');
require_once ("PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once ("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
   $mail->SMTPDebug =1;
   $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
   $mail->Port = 587;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
   $mail->Username = "my email address";
   $mail->Password = "email password";
   $mail->setFrom("email address","name");
   $mail->addAddress("my friend email address");
   $mail->Subject = 'First Mailer in Php';
   $mail->Body= 'this is first mail...sending through php code';
   if(!$mail->send()){
       echo "Message cannot be send"."<br/>";
       echo "MailerError".$mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
   }else{
       echo "<script>window.alert('Message has been sent');</script>";
   }

 ?>
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is happening here. ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't just add random stuff to your code in the hope that it will help! The only one of those requires you need is the autoloader. Base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), or at least the basic example provided in the readme.

From the error message you can see exactly what the problem is - while you have set `Username` and `Password` properties, you have disabled authentication. Enable it like this.

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
```

You're also using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/).

Comment: thanks a lot...@Snchro...Its work perfectly....thanks for  your consideration.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed this variable :

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

OR

```
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

Try one of them.

Comment: i tried,...but still there is an error....anyways thanks for your answer.. :) @prakashtank

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: Have you checked used gmail account settings? 
https://www.wpsitecare.com/gmail-smtp-settings/

Please check once.

Comment: i edited my post just now..and i have following errors which  i have mentioned above..help me to correct those errors..thanks..