# Lets Encrypt certificates causing issues with Avast?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Has anyone had issues with Lets Encrypt SSL certificates with Avast Internet Security?

We are getting some reports that Avast Internet Security is blocking the connection.
This is a screen shot from a clients computer (yes old windows, but still an issue regardless).

[image]

We have also had reports on a totally different server, hosted by a totally different company as well.  Same error, but this time on a mobile device using chrome.

Has anyone come across this yet?

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to one of the Lets Encrypt certificates expiring on September 30th, 2021.

Here's another question that talks about this: [LetsEncrypt Certificate invalid/expired when seemingly not in PHPMailer, TLS, Openssl, file_get_contents, Sep 30 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413223/letsencrypt-certificate-invalid-expired-when-seemingly-not-in-phpmailer-tls-op)

Comment: Most likely. And to solve it, you may remove the DST root from your Windows certificates and add ISRG Root X1 and R3 into your Windows certificates